# Error during a redirect header in php

Tags: php

I’ve this line:

```
header("Location: http://www.mysite.org/#login");
```

Why when the redirection occurred:

1. The url is not change but the given one,
2. The page is the good one but without images, CSS, JavaScript.

Comment: What does the console in your web inspector say about it, and what does `the url is not change but the given one`, are you saying that the URL never changes to `http://www.mysite.org/#login`

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.mysite.org/#login
```

Is not correct way of concatenating has code with the the url. 
The correct way is:-

```
http://www.mysite.org#login
```

Remove the / before #.

Comment: The `#` character is a [fragment identifier](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=3986#section-3.5), and has nothing to do with concatenation. The original `Location:` header is correct.